# Add List of Algorithms to content list with correct label

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms, front-matter

I'm using a custom template and can't seem to add the list of algorithms correctly. When I simply try `\listofalgorithms`, it results in this:
[image]

Instead of *Algorithm*, *Figure* is displayed in the list.

Other entries like Tables, Figures and Listings are predefined in the formatting as followed:

```
%*******************************************************
% List of Figures
%*******************************************************
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}
\listoffigures

\vspace{8ex}

%*******************************************************
% List of Tables
%*******************************************************
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables

\vspace{8ex}
% \newpage

%*******************************************************
% List of Listings
%*******************************************************
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\lstlistlistingname}{lol}
\lstlistoflistings

\vspace{8ex}
```

and in the configuration like this:

```
    % ********************************************************************
% layout of the TOC, LOF and LOT (LOL-workaround see next section)
% ********************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{titles}{tocloft}
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
% avoid page numbers being right-aligned in fixed-size box
\newlength{\newnumberwidth}
\settowidth{\newnumberwidth}{999} % yields overfull hbox warnings for pages > 999
\cftsetpnumwidth{\newnumberwidth}

% have the bib neatly positioned after the rest
\newlength{\beforebibskip}
\setlength{\beforebibskip}{0em}

% space for more than nine chapters
\newlength{\newchnumberwidth}
\settowidth{\newchnumberwidth}{.} % <--- tweak here if more space required
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@manychapters}}% <--- many chapters option
{%
    \addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\newchnumberwidth}%
    \addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{\newchnumberwidth}
    \addtolength{\cftsecindent}{\newchnumberwidth}
    \addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{\newchnumberwidth}
    \addtolength{\cftsubsecindent}{2\newchnumberwidth}
    \addtolength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{\newchnumberwidth}
}{\relax}%

% pagenumbers right after the titles
% parts
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@parts}}%
{%
    \renewcommand{\thepart}{\roman{part}}%
    \renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{\scshape}%  \MakeTextLowercase
    \renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{}%
    \renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}%
    \setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{\cftchapnumwidth}
    \renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\color{CTtitle}\normalfont}%
    \cftpagenumbersoff{part}
    \renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalfont}%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@dottedtoc}}{\relax}%
      {%
        \renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\hspace{1.5em}}%
        \renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}%
      }%
    \setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{1em}%
    \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{.1em}%
    \setlength{\beforebibskip}{1.5\cftbeforepartskip}%
}{\relax}
% chapters
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@nochapters}}%
    {\relax}%
    {%
        \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}%
        \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}%
        \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}%
        \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@dottedtoc}}{\relax}%
          {%
            \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\hspace{1.5em}}%
            \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}%
          }
        %\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{.1em}%
    }
% sections
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@nochapters}}%
    {%
        \setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{.1em}%
        \setlength{\beforebibskip}{1em}%
    }%
    {\relax}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase}%
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}%
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont}%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@dottedtoc}}{\relax}%
    {%
        \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\hspace{1.5em}}%
        \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}%
    }
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@tocaligned}}{\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{0em}}{\relax}
% subsections
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont}%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@dottedtoc}}{\relax}%
{%
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\hspace{1.5em}}%
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}%
}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@tocaligned}}{\renewcommand{\cftsubsecindent}{0em}}{\relax}
% subsubsections
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecpresnum}{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\normalfont}%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@dottedtoc}}{\relax}%
{%
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\hspace{1.5em}}%
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}%
}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@tocaligned}}{\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecindent}{0em}}{\relax}
% figures
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase}%
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\normalfont}%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@dottedtoc}}{\relax}%
{%
    \renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\hspace{1.5em}}%
    \renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}%
}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename~}%Fig.~}
\newlength{\figurelabelwidth}
\settowidth{\figurelabelwidth}{\cftfigpresnum~999}
\addtolength{\figurelabelwidth}{2.5em}
\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{\figurelabelwidth}
% tables
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase}%
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\normalfont}%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@dottedtoc}}{\relax}%
{%
    \renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\hspace{1.5em}}%
    \renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}%
}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\tablename~}%Tab.~}
\newlength{\tablelabelwidth}
\settowidth{\tablelabelwidth}{\cfttabpresnum~999}
\addtolength{\tablelabelwidth}{2.5em}
%\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{\tablelabelwidth}
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{\figurelabelwidth}
% listings
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@listings}}%
{%
    \newlistof{listings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}%
    \renewcommand{\cftlistingspresnum}{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase}%
    \renewcommand{\cftlistingsfont}{\normalfont}%
    \renewcommand{\cftlistingspresnum}{\lstlistingname~}%
    \renewcommand{\cftlistingspagefont}{\normalfont}%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@dottedtoc}}{\relax}%
    {%
        \renewcommand{\cftlistingsleader}{\hspace{1.5em}}%
        \renewcommand{\cftlistingsafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}%
    }
    \newlength{\listingslabelwidth}%
    \settowidth{\listingslabelwidth}{\cftlistingspresnum~999}%
    \addtolength{\listingslabelwidth}{2.5em}%
    %\cftsetindents{listings}{0em}{\listingslabelwidth}%
    \cftsetindents{listings}{0em}{\figurelabelwidth}%
    \let\l@lstlisting\l@listings%
    \let\lstlistoflistings\listoflistings%
}{\relax}%

% dirty work-around to get the spacing after the toc/lot/lof-titles right
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@parts}}%
{%
    \AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-\cftbeforepartskip}}}
}{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@nochapters}}%
        {\relax}%
        {\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-\cftbeforechapskip}}}}
}
```

I used `\usepackage{algorithm}` and `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` for my algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

**In classicthesis.sty:**

- After line 63, I added:

  ```latex
  \DeclareBoolOption{algorithm} % OBSOLETE - automatic check; load algorithm package and setup LoA
  ```
- After line 110, I added:

  ```latex
  \@ifpackageloaded{algorithm}
    {\setboolean{ct@algorithm}{true}%
    }{\relax}

  \ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@algorithm}}%
    {\RequirePackage{algorithm}%
    }{\relax}
  ```
- After line 565, I added:

  ```latex
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@algorithm}} %Check if Algorithm is loaded
  {
       \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Algorithm~}%Fig.~}
  }{\relax}
  ```

**In the file classicthesis-config.tex:**
You must call `algorithm` before the sty file. Thus, around line 180, my file looks like :

```latex
...

% ****************************************************************************************************
% 5. Setup code listings
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{listings}
%\lstset{emph={trueIndex,root},emphstyle=\color{BlueViolet}}%\underbar} % for special keywords
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,%C++,
  morekeywords={PassOptionsToPackage,selectlanguage},
  keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},%\bfseries,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  %identifierstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
  commentstyle=\color{Green}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\rmfamily,
  numbers=none,%left,%
  numberstyle=\scriptsize,%\tiny
  stepnumber=5,
  numbersep=8pt,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  %frameround=ftff,
  %frame=single,
  belowcaptionskip=.75\baselineskip
  %frame=L
}
% ****************************************************************************************************

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 6. Last calls before the bar closes
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Her Majesty herself
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{classicthesis}

...
```

**Finaly, in the file Contents.tex:**

```latex
...

   %*******************************************************
    % List of Listings
    %*******************************************************
    \phantomsection
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
    \newpage 

    \pdfbookmark[1]{\lstlistlistingname}{loa}
    % \lstlistoflistings
    \listofalgorithms

    \vspace{8ex}

...
```